# How to point two website in windows wamp server with same ip

Tags: windows, apache, wamp, virtualhost

I have two websites `www.test1.com` and `www.test2.com`.I hosted both sites in windows `wampp server` with same `IP` called xx.xxx.xx.xx .But while opening both sites `www.test1.com` is comming.Here `www.test1.com` files are in '`test1`' folder and `www.test2.com` are in '`test2`' folder.
I Tried virtual host in `wampp`...but its not working...

This is my `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/test1"
     ServerName test1
     ServerAlias test1.com
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/test2"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias test2.com
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/test2">
        AllowOverride All
    Require local
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

This is my `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      test1.com
127.0.0.1      test2.com
```

Comment: I just noticed that you tried www.test1.com and www.test2.com.  However, your vhosts are configured for test1.com and test2.com.  What happens if you try "test2.com"?

Comment: It is redirecting to test1.com.

Comment: Do you have 2 Dynamic DNS domain names setup for these 2 sites? Or are you just trying to access then remotely using you WAN IP Address?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to access remotely from two domains

Comment: Both domains are pointing to your Routers WAN ip address I assume. You have also Port forwarded your routers port 80 to the WAMPServer PC's ip address?

Comment: I don't have much idea about the windows and virtual hosting, can you please explain it with code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your domain names are going to the site defined first in the httpd-vhost.conf file because that is the default behaviour when Apache cannot find a site requested in the host definitions. It normally means you have done something wrong in the defining of your VHOSTS.

Your host definitions are a little wrong, and you are mixing Apache 2.2 and 2.4 security syntax which often causes problems, try these

```
# Should be the first VHOST definition so that it is the default virtual host
# Also access rights should remain restricted to the local PC and the local network
# So that any random ip address attack will recieve an error code and not gain access
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/test1"
     ServerName test1.com
     ServerAlias www.test1.com
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/test1">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/test2"
     ServerName test2.com
     ServerAlias www.test2.com
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/test2">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Now so that you can see the sites locally on the WAMPServer PC the hosts file should look like this. Remember, these entries only effect the PC containing the HOSTS file, and have no effect on internet access or the ability of a remote user to use these domain name.

```
# IPV4 loopback
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      test1.com
127.0.0.1      test2.com
# IPV6 loopback
::1      localhost
::1      test1.com
::1      test2.com
```

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply because we have weekend yesterday, when I tried this code on local wamp server its working fine, but when I tried in internet, only first one is working. please give any solution

Comment: I assume these are not the real domain names so I cannot try from here

Comment: I re installed wamp and used this same code again and somehow its working now. thanks

Answer (score -1):

The first line needs to be

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: I tried this also, but still it is not working, thanks

Comment: Only if you are using Apache 2.2, Apache 2.4 no longer uses the `NameVirtualHost` parameter

Comment: I am new to Stack Overflow.  Do I leave this poor answer or should I delete it?

Comment: Delete it, or expand it. You could say, "If you're using Apache 2.2, you'll also need to add a `NameVirtualHost *:80` somewhere before the `<VirtualHost>` directive.